# Is this component in falstad a tl431

Tags: simulation, scr, tl431, falstad

I'm self studying electronics, I am now familiarizing myself with the tl431, which is pretty much a "variable zener" aparently.

I was shown the following symbol.
[image]

I would like to simulate some circuits with it on falsad, I found this component, that looks pretty much alike and is called "SCR", after trying some circuits, I'm no longer sure it's the same component.

[image]

**The question:**

Is that a tl431?

If it is not, can I sumulate Tl431 in falstad?

Comment: #Joaquin Brandan, I have been playing with TL431 for a couple of years, mainly as a precision voltage reference for ADC. (1) TL431 / TL432 Precision Programmable Reference Datasheet - TI 2018:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?. TL431 is definitely not a SCR. Cheers.

Comment: No, an SCR/thyristor is not a zener diode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's nothing like the same part. One is (more or less) an op-amp + reference, the other is a thyristor.

As far as I know there is no support in Falstad for adding SPICE models as in full-featured circuit simulators such as PSpice or LTspice.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out some of the web based spice simulators to see if I can find one that  has this particular component then.

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan Why use web-based ones when you can just grab LTspice for free?

Comment: Because I make online notes that I leave for my future self as reference as I study, and I like to leave links in those notes that redirect me to the simulated examples that I used to explain the material so that I can quickly click on the link, fiddle with the simulator and quickly recall what was it all about.

Comment: Your future self might find these links broken or that those online simulators do not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

Is Falstad TL431 same as Texas Instrument TL431?

---

***Answer***

I have been playing with [Texas Instrument TL431](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf) for a couple of years, mainly as a precision voltage reference for ADC. TL431 is definitely not a SCR．

[image: TL431]

---

***Discussion and Recommendation***

I have been using Zener diode for ages, but I don't like it.  The reasons are:

1. They are not "precise".  I usually buy a couple of a particular value, say 3.0V Zener, but found them some 3.0V, some 3.2V etc.
2. The don't have a "continuous" range.  Eg, I can buy 3.0V Zener, but the next big step is 3.5V. In other words, it is too discrete.
3. So as a analog voltage reference to ADC etc, I just buy special purpose, fixed factory trimmed voltage reference ICs at as 1.024V, 2.5V, at 4.096V.
4. TL431 is good for prototyping and flexibility.  However, as shunt regulators, they are a bit hard and also time consuming to "program".

---

***References***

(1)  [TL431 / TL432 Precision Programmable Reference Datasheet - Texas Instrument　2018](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - TL431 Lab Log*

[image: tl431 1]

---

[image: tl431 2]

---

[image: kl431 3]

---

[image: kl431 4]